# Only echo if cell is not set to null in mysql / php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to only display an echo statement if a cell is not set to null.  I have the following code but keep getting an "HTTP ERROR 500" error when rendering my page since including this conditional statement.

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * from Stores");

<p class="description"><?php echo $row["Address1"];?><br />
<?php
$test=$row["Address2"];
if (isset($test)) {
echo $row["Address2"]<br />;
}?>
<?php echo $row["City"];?>, <?php echo $row["State"];?> <?php echo $row["Zip"];?></p>
```

I have also tried

```
if($row["Address2"] != NULL)
```

as my conditional statement, getting the same error.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: A 500 error means that there was a server-side error.  Check the PHP logs for the *actual* error message.

Comment: Please check the docs [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) you need this to retrieve the result data from your query and uses the mysqli extension instead of mysql

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error in PHP:

```
echo $row["Address2"]<br />;
```

You forgot to enclose the HTML string in quotes:

```
echo $row["Address2"] . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, `$row` is not being populated, so even if you fix the typo, it won't work for other reasons.

Comment: thanks, yes i did populate $row earlier in the code, but did not include this in my snippet.  my issue was that i forgot to include quotes around the HTML code.  thanks a lot for looking over my code and commenting!